# initialize long number

Tags: java, long-integer

I am working on one hardware interface application where i want to
initialize `long` data type value by any `8 byte` number(as it is fixed
key given in `dll` file) Example:

```
long fixedKey=0123456701234567; //error on this line

Error is : The literal 0123456701234567 of type int is out of range
```

I have seen on Primitive Data Types(*Java API*) range of `long` is from
**-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807** (19 digit number) .
      Obviously my entered number (16 digit number) is in the
range of `long` data type, so why i am getting this kind of error.

Comment: Apart from the answer, are you sure you need that `leading 0`. It would make your literal to be interpreted in Octal.

Comment: @Rohit you are right but as i mentioned in question it is fixed key given in dll file so i cant change this number

Comment: If it's not meant to be interpreted as an octal number, leave off the leading `0`, write: `long fixedKey = 123456701234567L;`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

append `L` to the end to make it a `long literal`

```
long fixedKey=0123456701234567L; //error on this line
```

Comment: But take note of the comment above about that number being interpreted as octal!

Answer (score 1):

You should add an L suffix to your number. Also, are you sure you want to express your number in octal?

Answer (score 1):

Use `L` to show that it is a long type  like

```
long fixedKey=0123456701234567L;
```